# Making it safe to call a hook from outside of the Redux Provider, when it access the Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a hook `useGetFooId` that attempts to get a Foo ID from the Redux store with fallback logic:

1. If the Foo ID is set in the Redux store, it returns the ID from there (but it's expected that in some cases, it's not set in the Redux store).
2. Otherwise, if the Foo ID is not available from the Redux store, it falls back to trying to get the ID from a few other, less reliable places.

It looks something like:

```js
const useGetFooId = () => {
  const { fooId: fooIdFromSelector } = useSelector(uiSelector);
  const fooIdFromLessReliablePlace = getFooIdFromLessReliablePlace();
  const fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace = getVeryUnreliableFooId();

  return fooIdFromSelector
    ?? fooIdFromLessReliablePlace
    ?? fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace
    ?? null;
}
```

**Now, I want to make `useGetFooId` safe to call from outside of the Redux Provider.** (The Foo ID is relevant to some display logic in an error boundary component at the root of the application). Right now, if it's called from outside the Provider, it gets this error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'store')`.

The desired behavior is basically: If `useGetFooId` is called from outside of the selector, it uses the same fallback logic as if `fooId` was undefined in the selector (so, it should return `fooIdFromLessReliablePlace ?? fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace ?? null`).

Is there a supported way to conditionally access the Redux store only if the Provider is available, or something? I originally thought to wrap it in try/catch, but it seems as though this violates the rules of hooks: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16026

Comment: Going to ask the painful question here, why is it outside the provider? Does it have to be? Providers are react's version of angular's dependency injection system, you're actually losing a lot more than you think you are by doing it this way. If you need this ID and you're outside the redux provider, then the application structure is kind of telling you that you shouldn't be outside the redux provider and it seems like you're fighting it.

Comment: Thanks @AdamJenkins I also really wanted to ask the same question. Seems odd to make a hook to access a context, and then use it outside the context knowingly. ‍♂️

Comment: Alternatively, the other solution is to not use the hook and to just "pass the id as a prop" (if it comes from an error being caught in the error boundary, then make the id part of the error you throw and the ErrorBoundary can pass the id down to it's children). Either way, if you continue down this path, you're only a hair away from circular dependencies and spaghetti code.

Comment: Yeah, I know 99% of the time if someone is asking this, the answer is probably "you shouldn't want to do this in the first place". In my case, we have an "error occurred" component that tries to use the Foo ID to show the most relevant customer support email address. And we want to do `<ErrorBoundary><ReduxProvider><ErrorBoundary>...</...`, with the outer error boundary to catch errors that occur in the Redux Provider itself. And the behavior of the outer error component should be exactly the same as how the inner one behaves when the Foo ID is undefined in Redux. So it makes sense to reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your custom to subscribe to changes from the store using the store object directly instead of the `useSelector` hook which can't be called conditionally, e.g. can't be called conditionally in a `try/catch`.

See [store.subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener).

Use a `useEffect` hook to instantiate a listener that can select the current `fooId` value from the store and save it into a local React state. You can surround the store subscription logic in a `try/catch`.

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

const useGetFooId = () => {
  const [fooIdFromSelector, setFooIdFromSelector] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
        const { fooId } = uiSelector(store.getState());
        setFooIdFromSelector(fooId);
      });

      return unsubscribe;
    } catch(error) {
      // some error happened during the store subscription
      // handle/log/ignore/etc, it's up to you
    }
  }, []);

  const fooIdFromLessReliablePlace = getFooIdFromLessReliablePlace();
  const fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace = getVeryUnreliableFooId();

  return fooIdFromSelector
    ?? fooIdFromLessReliablePlace
    ?? fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace
    ?? null;
};
```

Comment: If the OP is using react 18 then it's a built-in https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore

Answer (score 1):

You only need the logic outside of the provider, and not the selector, because:

> The desired behavior is basically: If useGetFooId is called from
> outside of the selector, it uses the same fallback logic as if fooId
> was undefined in the selector (so, it should return
> fooIdFromLessReliablePlace ?? fooIdFromVeryUnreliablePlace ?? null).

Create a function called `getFooId` that optionally receives an `id` (`id` can also be `undefined`, and use it in the custom hook, and directly in the error boundary (`id` would be `undefined`):

```
// only call other functions if the previous value is `null` or `undefined`
const getFooId = id => id
  ?? getFooIdFromLessReliablePlace()
  ?? getVeryUnreliableFooId()
  ?? null;

const useGetFooId = () => {
  const { fooId: fooIdFromSelector } = useSelector(uiSelector);

  return getFooId(fooIdFromSelector);
}
```